# Cython NameError: name ' blah ' is not defined. Cython magic in Jupyter not working properly?

Tags: python, cython, nameerror

I am trying to make some code run faster in Jupyter using cython but for some reason it doesn't "remember" functions after the %%cython cell has been run. This doesn't seem to be a problem with any other examples I have found online ( For instance : https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/11/live-coding-cython-ising-model/ ).
I am using Cython 0.29.15 and python 3.7.3.

Example:

```py
%load_ext cython
```

```py
%%cython

def function(x):
    y = 2*x
    return y
```

```py
function(1)
```

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d7befaefa369> in <module>
----> 1 function(1)

NameError: name 'function' is not defined
```

I have tried `cpdef` and `cdef` but those provide the same error output.

Another Example :

```py
%%cython 

cpdef int a = 0
for i in range(10):
    a += i

print(a)
```

Nothing prints

Next cell:

```py
print(a)
```

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-bca0e2660b9f> in <module>
----> 1 print(a)

NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: Please include a [mre] in your question instaed of images

Comment: please also include the output printed to the console that started jupyter.

Comment: It works for me (and I guess many others). You could run in verbose `%%cython --verbose` and hope to see more. Something isn't right with your installation, but I doubt someone will be able to help much remote.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work.

```py
%load_ext cython
```

```py
%%cython

def function(x):
    y = 2*x
    return y
```

```py
function(1)
```

```py
2
```

There was some installation problem maybe. I am not sure, I'm a novice at this stuff but

### here is what I did:

.Tried reinstalling cython-- didn't work.

.Tried reinstalling anaconda3-- didn't work.

.Noticed that my terminal was using python2 then switched that to python3
(https://dev.to/irfnhm/how-to-set-python3-as-a-default-python-version-on-mac-4jjf)

.Then reinstalled anaconda3 (https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-successfully-install-anaconda-on-a-mac-and-actually-get-it-to-work-53ce18025f97)

### .Now cython works!!

I have no idea why this worked (again, novice) but hope this helps someone in the future possibly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I'm writing my own solution hoping to help some lost souls out there.

Similarly to what happened to OP, I declared a function inside a `%%cython` cell, but when I printed `dir()` such function was not found in the local scope. Looking at the doc of cython I found a flag called `--cplus` (also `-+`) which outputs C++ instead of C, and that was my problem.

But for some reason the compilation failed silently, there's an issue about this https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3751#issuecomment-679162419 .

Also, another way to debug the error was to migrate the code outside of jupyter, into a normal .py file and then compile it.