# Why i have Cython magic name error after linux reinstallation?

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, cython

I am facing a problem with Cython. I have a jupyter notebook with a lot of computation. I wrote Python + Cython code a few days ago. Everything worked. But yesterday I reinstalled my linux, installed anaconda3 and tried to run my code. It stopped working) I think the problem is in the anaconda settings, but I don't know how to solve it.
My problem is the same as [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61270962/cython-nameerror-name-blah-is-not-defined-cython-magic-in-jupyter-not-work). But my terminal is using Python3.8.3, so i don't know what to do. Here is some sample code that doesn't work.

```
%load_ext Cython
import Cython
```

---

```
%%cython
cdef class Test:
    cdef text
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = 'Hello!'
        
    cdef print_text(self):
        print(self.text)
        
    cdef set_text(self, text):
        self.text = text
```

---

```
t = Test()
```

---

*NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 t = Test()
NameError: name 'Test' is not defined*

---

```
def do():
    print('Do')
```

---

```
do()
```

---

*Do*

---

```
%%cython

def do1():
    print('Do1')
```

---

```
do1()
```

---

*NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 do1()
NameError: name 'do1' is not defined*

So the cells with `%%cython` magic is not working. I tried the `def`, `cdef`, `cpdef` like the guy from link. But it's still not working.

Comment: I think https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3751#issuecomment-679162419 is at core of your problems. Due to a bug, distutils-errors during the compilation aren't reported - look at c-level log to see what the problem is (maybe gcc is not installed).